# Eclipse Ide Console not showing ouput of the current code

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-neon

In Eclipse Neon after writing a code, when pressing run, output of other code, (previously done) are showing. The output of the code that i have written is not showing. What is the cause off the problem ? Is it related to workspace ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just clicking Run runs whatever program you executed last. It does not switch to your new code.

To be sure of executing your new program right click on the class containing your 'main' method and select 'Run As > Java Program' (assuming this is Java as you haven't told us your programming language).

Comment: The path for the project is changed may be. How can i change the current path of the project ? Btw i am using Java

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you are asking. If you have a new question please ask a Question.

Comment: The thing is after i have written a java code, after i tried to run it, other previous program is running. There is a list of previous programs in the list of run. I want to to know what should i do?

Comment: The list in the Run menu is just a quick way to run the various programs. It does **not** mean that the programs are currently running.